# Software and hardware technologies used for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What were Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-were-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user-built-with)

Hi, folks

What technologies are used by stackoverflow.com?
What DB is actually handling queries, how much server stuff is turned up and finally in what language is implemented.

Sorry for poor language.
Thanks

Comment: This has been answered at blog.stackoverflow.com before

Answer (score -1):

[Blog Overflow: What was Stack Overflow Built with?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/)

> framework   *Microsoft ASP.NET*
>
> language   *C#*
>
> development environment   *Visual Studio*
>
> web framework   *ASP.NET MVC*
>
> browser framework   *jQuery*
>
> database   *SQL Server 2008*
>
> data access layer   *LINQ to SQL*
>
> source control   *Subversion (now Mercurial through Kiln)*
>
> compare tool   *Beyond Compare*
>
> source control integration   *VisualSVN (now, VisualHg)*
>
> We have a few other minor dependencies as well, such as *ReCaptcha*,
> *DotNetOpenId*, and the *WMD* control (which we subsequently rewrote), but
> that’s about it.